# Simple java socket client, what throws this ConnectException?

Tags: java, sockets, connectexception

I'm writing a very simple client for my very simple server.  Line 17 throws a ConnectException at runtime if the server isn't running, I don't know why.  I have looked through the docs for Socket's constructor and getInputStream(), but neither of them throw the ConnectException.  I looked at the docs for the CE, and it says "Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port)."  That is exactly true, the server isn't running, but I don't know how to know this other than trial and error, why isn't it in the docs for Socket?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientLesson {

    //declare vars
    static Socket socket;
    static BufferedReader inputReader;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("Lithium", 55555);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        }
        try {
   this is the problem --> inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.print("couldn't get I/O stream");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }  
        String fromServer;
        while ((fromServer = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(fromServer);
        }
        inputReader.close();
        socket.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer [here][1] that may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116625/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-vs-java-net-connectexception/28622382#28622382

Answer (score 1):

I just realized the problem is entirely different...the ConnectException is thrown by the Socket constructor, and handled as an IOException, since CE is a subtype, that makes sense to me now.  I'm getting a NPE at line 17, but I was confused by the terminal output, here it is:

```
nexus@Lithium ~/Desktop/Java Workspace/networking $ java ClientLesson 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ClientLesson.main(ClientLesson.java:17)
```

I didn't understand those two were separate issues.  Now I know the problem is line 17 should check to see if the first try was successful before calling methods on the socket.

Comment: Connection refused means there is no service running on the port you attempted to connect to.  This is a configuration problem or a server side problem.

Comment: When you get an exception, log or print *its* message. Don't just make up one of your own that masks what the actual problem was. If you nested your try-catch blocks properly the problem would not have arisen in the first place. At present you are allowing exception to continue despite the connect exception.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - the problem was with the client code, the OP says the problem only occurs when the server is not running and a connection is attempted, ie I was trying to attempt connection to a port with no service and handle the error gracefully.

Comment: @EJP - that is good advice to print the message from the exception, I have started doing that.  Actually, that is what confused me at first, I got the "Connection Refused" message, the result of ex.toString(), but I didn't realize the program continued on and encountered a second error later, the NPE.  I ended up putting a System.exit() in some of the catch blocks, right after the println(ex.toString()) call.  Can you post an answer that suggests a better arrangement/nesting of the try blocks so I understand what you mean?