# java.net.SocketTimeoutException vs java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, sockets

When connecting to a server with a Java client socket I had this two different connection timeout exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381) 

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
```

I checked the documentation but for `SocketTimeoutException` it's written that "Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept", but this is not the situation in my case. Because I am getting it during connection establishment.

What is the difference between between these two exceptions? Actually I was expecting getting the `ConnectException` in any connection problem (firewall, port down, etc.)

Comment: Isn't connection establishment related to socket read or accept?

Comment: @Raj No, it is related to *`connect()`* or `accept().` It has nothing to do with `read().`

Comment: @EJP Yes, I agree but my point was about this "Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept." but this is not the situtaion in my case." And I was trying to convey If you are trying to connect than you fall in one category. In this case not read but accept.

Comment: @Raj Not `read()` but `accept()` *or* `connect()`. In this case, `connect()`, as is evident from the OP's code.

Answer (score 6):

Also came here looking for the same answer, seemingly [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect-java.net.SocketAddress-int-) can be easily misinterpreted:

> Connects this socket to the server with a specified timeout value. A
>   timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. The connection
>   will then block until established or an error occurs.

The key part that I overlooked in this is "an error"... going to [the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c#l255) I can see how Java's `connect()` is actually invoking the Linux `connect()`:

```
if (timeout <= 0) {
    connect = connect(args...);
    if (connect == -1 && errno == EINPROGRESS) {
        connect = poll(args...);
        // try again on EINTR
    }
} else {
    // Go to non-blocking mode for a timeout.
    connect = connect(args...);

    if (connect!=0) {
        // not EINPROGRESS? -> throw ConnectException
        while (!connect || !error || timedout) {
            connect = poll(args...);
            // error / timedout handling
        }
        if (timedout) {
            // throw SocketTimeoutException
        }
    }
}

/* report the appropriate exception */
if (error) {
    //EINVAL; throw SocketException
    //EINTR; throw InterruptedIOException
    //EPROTO; throw ProtocolException
    //ECONNREFUSED;ETIMEDOUT; throw ConnectException
    //EHOSTUNREACH; throw NoRouteToHostException
    //EADDRNOTAVAIL; throw NoRouteToHostException
    //EISCONN, EBADF, other; throw SocketException
}
```

i.e. I think `SocketTimeoutException` is being thrown when the network is slow, or the host doesn't respond at all. Checking `man connect`, I can see that `ECCONNREFUSED` must be thrown when "No-one listening on the remote address", i.e. and an ICMP tells us so.

This means that if like me, you were trying to use the `timeout` to connect to a (localhost) socket that wasn't ready to be connected to, you are SOL'd.

Answer (score 2):

You will get a `SocketTimeoutException` if you specify a timeout on `connect(),` or if you've called `setSoTimeout()` on a `Socket` or `ServerSocket` and a `read()` or `accept()` times out, respectively. In the case of `connect(),` this is a serious problem: what you're trying to connect to either doesn't exist or is behind a firewall, and you can't tell which.

You will get `connection refused` if the peer *actively* refused your connection request, which usually means there is nothing listening at the port you specified. Note that unlike a timeout, this means a response *was* received, and it was negative.

Comment: So if I get SocketTimeoutException how can I understand if I get it during communication (during read) or I could not connect to the server.

Comment: @cacert You will get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out during communication.

Answer (score 1):

ConnectException is thrown on packet filter/firewall etc.

SocketTimeoutException is thrown when you have set a specific timeout on your socket, and it has not received anything before the timeout.

Example with a `ServerSocket`:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket... // Create server socket
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);  
serverSocket.accept();
```

If the `ServerSocket` has not received anything within 1000 ms it will throw a `SocketTimeoutException`. Note that this exception is thrown for all sockets that use timeouts, not only `ServerSocket`. This means that a `Socket` object that throws a `SocketTimeoutException` hasn't got anything back from the called server before the timeout.

To fix the problem you can either make sure that the server responds quicker, or set a higher timeout value.

Comment: Both of these errors happening on the client side when client tries to connect to the server.No accept or read operation on my side. Check stack trace please.

Comment: @cacert: When using a socket with a timeout and the server does not respond to any of your packets within the timeout, it will throw the sockettimeoutexception. You don't have to explicitly call read or accept, but it can also happen during TCP handshake. If there is a timeout during handshake (or initialization of socket), the exception is thrown in java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) :)

Comment: That means if I dont set a connect timeout on the client socket, then I will get ConnectException ?

Comment: @cacert: Yes, probably :) I am not 100% sure of how Socket is implemented, but that should be the logical way. EDIT: socketConnect() calls a native method, so that will probably depend on underlying C-implementation.

Comment: Interesting fact. I checked and it works that way. Then can I have one more question..If I need to know I get connect or read timeout, how can I understand I get which one.. I get the same exception with different message as far as I see.

Comment: @cacert Why? You know whether you were doing a `connect()` or a `read().` The situation isn't ambiguous.

Comment: @cacert: You can see in which method the exception was thrown. If it was in socketConnect it is a connection problem, if it is accept or read it is timeout

Answer (score -1):

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

When you are not able to connect due to unavailability of the peer. 
Your second query, what about read? Than you will get

```
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Third possibility `connection refused` if peer is active but refused the connection.

Comment: Connect timeouts aren't caused by the peer being inactive, they are caused by the peer *host* being inactive or contra it a firewall rule; and if  the peer is active it can't refuse the connection.