# What is the exact difference between "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" and "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"?

Tags: java, timeout, jax-ws, httpurlconnection

In my logs I can find the two following stacktraces

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)   
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) 
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)    
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1147)   
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)    
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257) 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)    ... 127 more
```

and

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out   
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)   
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:656)   
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)  
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)  
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1147)   
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)   
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)    
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)   
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)    ... 50 more
```

Both exceptions occur during webservice calls with JAXWS-RI (reference implementation). What is the exact difference between these two exceptions.

To configure timeouts I set some properties in the context, one is for the connect timeout:

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> context = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
context.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 90000);
context.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 90000);
```

As far as I can see from the logs, only the `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`seems to respect the `JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` settings.

`java.net.ConnectExceptions` occurs before 90 seconds are over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622382/948784).

The two mentioned exceptions are coming from native code. As [user5436](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2782193/user5436) already mentioned, the [`SocketTimeoutExceptions`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c#l436) occurs when a timeout is set and no connection can be established in the desired time. The [`ConnectException`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c#l500) is thrown, when an error occurs while trying to establish the connection. Confusingly this can also be a *Connect Timeout*.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect without proof that one of them comes from a `connect(..., timeout)` path and the other comes from a path without a connect timeout specified. In the former case I would expect `SocketTimeoutException`, in the latter `ConnectException`.

Answer (score -1):

They are rather at low level in terms of network transport layers, and thrown by errors at different states of TCP/IP state machine. You can research on the TCP sockets diagram if interested but most network application (which JAX-WS is) users or programmers need not care about these low level details other than the fact that network is not working.

They are coming from different code paths, one is setting up a http connection, the other, https. Https is based on SSL, i.e. secure socket layer, which is trying to connect the socket with different parameters.

The bottom line is that these code paths were written by other humans, probably ancient programmers. And at the time they decided to throw one Exception rather than the other. We need not fuss too much about it.

Comment: The fact that one is HTTP and one is HTTPS is irrelevant. Both exceptions were thrown by the same method. SSL does not 'try to connect the socket with different parameters'.

Comment: You should find and read the source code files and above stack traces before marking other people's comments as irrelevant.

Comment: In case of HTTP, the connection is created by a wrapper function New() in java that omits timeOut parameter, that means the default -1 is passed in, eventually to socket connect(). In case of HTTPS, the user specified timeOut is passed in. That also explains why the setting is respected in one, not the other. Then down the code paths, they are interrupted differently based on different timeOuts(one being not specified.), thus different Exceptions.