# set timeout for opening a Socket to unreachable host

Tags: java

I am wondering on how to set the timeout for opening a socket to a non existing host(which raises a java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host). Following code as example:

```
private static final int SAMPLESIZE = 32;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] times = new long[SAMPLESIZE];
    int tryNum = 0;
    long time;
    System.out.println("measuring timeout on opening a java.net.Socket to unreachable host...\n\n");
    while(tryNum < times.length) {
        System.out.print("try #" + tryNum + "...");
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.15.15",12345);
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        times[tryNum] = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println(times[tryNum] + "ms");
        tryNum++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n\ntimes:");
    long average = 0;
    tryNum = 0;
    for(long result : times) {
        System.out.print("#" + tryNum + ":" + result + "ms | ");
        average += result;
        tryNum++;
    }
    System.out.print("\b\b");
    System.out.println("\n\naverage: " + Math.round(average/tryNum) + "ms");
}
```

If I let that run on my artix sys, it has an average timeout of around 3s. On my Win10VM it has around 21s. Is there a way to specify the timeout? Just stumbled upon hints, that the exception is raised after "a" timeout, but I can't find how to do so. As far as I understood, the setSoTimeout(int timeout) only takes effect on the read() of the inputStream of this socket.
Any hints are highly appreciated ;)

UPDATE: I just realized, that it is not a NoRouteToHostException on Win10, but a ConnectException. This lead to finding this:
[java.net.SocketTimeoutException vs java.net.ConnectException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116625/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-vs-java-net-connectexception)
Besides this shenanigans my question remains: is there a way to specify a timeout, now as I know for every possible way(OS), on opening a socket?

Comment: Create empty Socket object, then call connect method with timeout arg.

Comment: this is correct, sir. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: Unreachable host. Non-existent host. No route to host. These are three different conditions, not one condition. Which is it?

Comment: Host is unreachable because there is no route to host, I guess. The host does exist though. I don't understand neither what the difference between unreachable and no route is, nor I understand what that has to do with a fixed timeout. i already stated, that the solution presented by Hitobat is working. So....?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as Hitobat mentioned as comment, the solution is to use the connect() method with the timeout argument, like so:

```
private static final int SAMPLESIZE = 32;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] times = new long[SAMPLESIZE];
    int tryNum = 0;
    long time;
    System.out.println("measuring timeout on opening a java.net.Socket to unreachable host...\n\n");
    while(tryNum < times.length) {
        System.out.print("try #" + tryNum + "...");
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Socket s;
        try {
            SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.15.15",12345);
            s = new Socket();
            s.connect(sa,  TIMEOUT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        times[tryNum] = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println(times[tryNum] + "ms");
        tryNum++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n\ntimes:");
    long average = 0;
    tryNum = 0;
    for(long result : times) {
        System.out.print("#" + tryNum + ":" + result + "ms | ");
        average += result;
        tryNum++;
    }
    System.out.print("\b\b");
    System.out.println("\n\naverage: " + Math.round(average/tryNum) + "ms");
}
```

Thx to Hitobat!

Comment: You must close the socket in the `catch` block if the connect fails. Otherwise you are lekaing sockets.

Comment: That is correct. Thought I'd include some hurdles for our copy-paste followers ;) Jokes aside, I just did not recognize and did not really care as it was just for testing purposes. Non the less, it is correct and I edited the answer.