# intelli-J Tcp Client c++ Server broken pipe

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu, intellij-idea, tcpclient

I'm trying to run a client-server project using ubuntu.
The client is running on intelli-J using java-fx, and the server in eclipse c++.
The server is no problem, it works as expected when I run a c++ client.
Problem is that when I run client in intelli-J, it throws out excpetion in the line where it has to get a string from the server (shown in code), and the server throws

```
  "an error occured: Broken pipe"
```

here's my client code (as I've said, the server runs perfectly using a c++ client) , I wanted to ask if you see any problem:

```
try {

     Socket clientSocket = new Socket(this.ipAddress, 
     this.portNumber);

     DataOutputStream outToServer = new 
     DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

     BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new  
     InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

  while (true) {
                fromSceneBuilder = "1 xyz e 148 2010 8.8 this ";
                outToServer.writeBytes(fromSceneBuilder);
                //the server needs to return "success" to fromServer string
                fromServer = inFromServer.readLine();  //throws exception
                System.out.println(fromServer); 
               }   //end while

            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If you know any better way to do this let me know..
while searching I've found this : [Simple java socket client, what throws this ConnectException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676395/simple-java-socket-client-what-throws-this-connectexception)

but it's now really my problem..
HELP..?

Comment: broken pipe is an indication that your client is trying to write on the socket that has already been closed. So, you need to look on the server side

Comment: but the broken pipe is on the server's side..

Comment: broken pipe essentially means that peer has closed the socket on which your current process is trying to write. So, in your case its the c++ server that has got the broken pipe error, meaning thereby that your java code has closed the socket